# rewrite URL with multiple parameters using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

What I want to achieve?

> www.example.com/list/1/2

my .htacess file

```
RewriteRule ^list/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) list.php?id=$1&p=$2 [NC,L]
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^list/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) list.php?id=$1&p=$2 [NC,L]
```